# Rails remove old models with migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, refactoring

I have a bunch of rails models that I'm re-writing into a single model to simplify my code and reduce unnecessary tables.

I'm wondering what the best way to delete a model class and its table is.  I want past migrations to still succeed, but I don't want to leave the empty models lying around.

Do I have to manually delete the old migrations that reference these models, then manually delete the class files?

Does anyone have any tips for the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about doing `ruby script/destroy model`? That should take care of the model and the migration.

Comment: what about later migrations that add data to this model?  does script/destroy search the migrations or does it just delete the initial one that created the table?

Comment: Later migrations will need their own `script/destory migration migration_name`. A good way to think about it, it is the undo of the genarate command. So, no it also won't search for other migrations that alter the same model.

Comment: right, so then the final answer to all of this is that I can use script/destroy, but I also need to manually edit any migrations that might contain refs to these deleted models.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 23):

**All in one solution.**

Run the following commands:

```
rails destroy model ModelName
rails g migration DropTableModelName
```

The former will generate a new migration file which should looks like this:

```
class DropTableModelName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :model_name
  end
end
```

Now run `db:migrate` and you're done.

Comment: One more point.
We need to recover `db/migrate/20181106030807_create_model_names.rb`-ish file by `git checkout` (or something like that), right?

Comment: Migration files should remain the same, its modifications/removal/recover aren't recommended.

Answer (score 15):

If you'd like to completely get rid of of a model and its table do this:

```
rails destroy model Name
```

Comment: This won't generate a `remove_table` migration but delete the `create` one instead. So the model will still be in `schema.rb`...

Comment: This will just remove model file. Database table will remain, this should be removed with migration.

Answer (score 8):

The question is a bit stale now, but I just did:

```
rails destroy scaffold <ModelName> -p
```

The -p flag shows "pretend" output, which is good for seeing what will happen.  Remove the '-p' flag and the results will match the output.  This cleaned the entire collection of M-V-C files + testing + js files + the original migration, no problem.

I guess if you are one who likes to hand edit your migrations and include multiple steps in each, losing the original migration could break db:setup, so buyer beware.  Keeping one action == one migration file should avoid this potential snafu.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how far into development or production you are, you may want to migrate the models out safely using a migration to remove/backup data or what not. Then as bobbywilson0 suggested, using

```
script/destroy model
```

or if you rspec anything

```
script/destroy rspec_model
```

This will remove any spec tests as well.

Or you can always just drag them to the trash folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this one at [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations).
But I suggest, if it is possible, you should delete the models and all references to the models. This will probably save time later as you don't need to maintain the dead code in the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather have a manual based answer:

First run the following command to identify which migrations you want removed:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

Feel free to `grep -i` on it too if you're confident of your naming scheme.

Make note of all the "add x to model name" and similar alterations to your Model. These can be removed using:

```
rails d migration AddXToModelName
```

Do this for every migration besides the initial create migration. The following command will take care of the initial create migration and the files associated with the model:

```
rails d model ModelName
```