# How do I remove a model and its table in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm diving into RoR and I need to remove a model and its table, as well as update the other models that reference it.  I did a search on google and SO and the best answer I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981777/rails-remove-old-models-with-migrations), but the answer is unclear to me.  The final consensus was to use the `ruby script/destroy model` method and then *"manually edit any migrations that might contain refs to these deleted models"*  It's this last part that I'm unclear about.  I want to delete the models for my `user` and `profile` models and tables...

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
        t.string :email
        t.string :password

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end

class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :profiles do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :profiles
  end
end
```

and update the `article` model and table that references them...

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :articles do |t|
        t.string :title
        t.text :body
        t.datetime :published_at
        t.string :image

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :articles
  end
end



class AddUserIdToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :articles, :user_id, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :articles, :user_id
  end
end
```

Can I just do `ruby script/destroy user` and then call the `self.down` methods in the `article` migrations?  If so, how do I call the 'self.down` methods and in what order?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Just delete it with

```
ruby script/destroy model user
ruby script/destroy model profile
```

And then rollback your database, or self.down with this :

```
rake db:rollback
```

Now you can safely delete your migration file.